# javascript: `Date()` and `new Date()`

Tags: javascript, date

why do `Date()` and `new Date()` give different results? How is `Date()` implemented and why is it implemented like this?

```
typeof(Date())
>>  "string"
typeof(new Date())
>>  "object"
```

Comment: [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date): *"JavaScript `Date` objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript `Date` as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the `new` operator) will return a string rather than a `Date` object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript `Date` objects have no literal syntax."*

Comment: I would say the first comment is the actual answer and should be submitted as an answer

Comment: Many built in "constructors" behave differently when called with `new` vs without. E.g. `String(42)` vs `new String(42)`.

Comment: @felix but ... why? Who needs `String` objects?

Comment: @Jonas: Nobody at all :P Maybe a side effect of having string (and number) *methods*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) behavior:

> **Note**: JavaScript `Date` objects can only be instantiated by calling JavaScript `Date` as a constructor: calling it as a regular function (i.e. without the `new` operator) will return a string rather than a `Date` object; unlike other JavaScript object types, JavaScript `Date` objects have no literal syntax.

You can find it in ECMAScript 1st edition already, from 1997 (https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf):

> 15.9.2.8 **Date()**
> A string is created and returned as if by the expression **new Date ().toString()**

Answer (score 2):

> How is Date() implemented ?

There are some ways for a function to determine wether it was called with `new`, one is checking the value of `this` and another one would be `new.target` (pseudocode):

```
 function Date() {
   if(!(this instanceof Date)) {
     return "string";
  }
}
```

However the internal objects are usually not written in JS itself, but rather in the language running JS.

> and why is it implemented like this?

You will never get an answer to that. No one made bad design decisions.